# I can't pass the returned character array from a function, as an argument in another function

Tags: c

In the following code I want to print a 3*3 matrix with `o` filled in the boxes. But I don't get the desired output. If you run the program using a C99 compiler the first matrix output is what I expect and the second output is what I get.

If instead of making an initializing function `init()` if I do the initialization in `main()` it works fine. But I don't know why the array isn't properly returned from `init()`so that I can use it as an argument in `display()` function.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    char * init(int a)
    {
        char tic[a][a];
        for(int i=0;i<=(a-1);i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=(a-1);j++)
            {
                tic[i][j]='o';
            }
        }
        display(a,tic);//This is extra code just to show what I desire to print through this program
        return (char * )tic;
    }


    int display(int a,char tic[a][a])
    {                                                                        
        for(int i=0;i<=(a-1);i++)   
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=(a-1);j++)                   
            {
                if(j==0)
                {
                    printf("\n-------------\n|");
                }
            printf(" %c |",tic[i][j]);
            }
        }
            printf("\n-------------");

            return 0;
    }


    int main()
    {
        int a=3;
        display(a,init(a));

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Sebivor my question is totally different

Comment: Seems like you are trying to return the address of a local variable (array) from the `init` function. You can't do that. The scope of a local variable is only within that function. Read about 'global variables' and `malloc()`.

Comment: It's actually not about scope, but storage duration. Scope is the visibility of an identifier, and there are no errors related to that in this code. Storage duration, however, or more explicitly, referring to an object outside of its storage duration...

Comment: Are you perhaps not reading a book? Because I don't often notice questions like this from people who tell me "I'm reading K&R2E", for example. No, this kind of question usually comes from people who tell me "I'm learning C as my first programming language!" -double-cringe- Suffice to say, whichever method you're using to learn C isn't going to work for you if you're not grasping the basics of procedural programming; in the realm of C, demons lurk behind corners, and you want to make sure your resources are accurate! You don't want massive gaps that come from trial and error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [C11/6.2.4p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p2):

> The lifetime of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime. If an object is referred to outside of its lifetime, the behavior is undefined. The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

In this case, if you can decipher the entirety of that, you'll have understood what's wrong. Your code uses a pointer which became indeterminate when the function returned, and as a result your code invoked undefined behaviour, and probably crashed.

Call it *scope*, if you must, but the standard has a different definition for *scope*, and it is in the standard I place my trust.

My bigger concern is how you got here, with that question, after reading any reasonable educational resource... This seems more like a guess, like you think you can learn C by *trial and error*. You might get lucky, I suppose, but the odds are heavily stacked against you.

You should *read a book*, if you aren't already; it'll probably save you many long nights toiling over *the evasive bug that disappears when you uncomment the unused variable*...

Comment: just a little doubt: when i initialize the array in init(), the values are stored at particular addresses which are pointed by different array elements of tic. tic is local, so becomes undefined after the init() execution is over, thats okay. But the values at those addresses remain don't they? And i am passing the address of the first element of tic. So, even if tic doesn't exist ,the address i am returning from init should point to the required value, wont it?

Comment: The values at those addresses *might* remain, but the only way you can access them is by referring to the object outside of its lifetime (which according to the standard quote, results in undefined behaviour). Your programs *might also* leak critical data in a similar form of vulnerability similar to heartbleed (which is surprisingly related; that's how critical you should be of this). Other functions *might change your data*. We can't say what *will certainly happen*, because the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: If i declare the array( tic) in the main() function , and then pass the array pointer to the initializing function, then it works fine. But in this case too, it gets  outside the lifetime of the array when it gets outside main(). So why is it working when i am passing the array pointer as an argument to a function from main(). Why does the array stay within lifetime? Also, it would be great if you can suggest a source where this particular concept is explained. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm only going to explain this *once more*, *"the behaviour is undefined"* means *"we can't say what will happen"*. If that's okay with you, if you want to write non-portable, fragile and downright unreliable code that *seems to work on your system for now*, and that's perfectly fine with you, then so be it, but *please, don't inflict it upon us* and **please don't call this C**! Think about the two words *undefined* and *behaviour* for a moment... Those two words don't necessarily convey "it will work the same way every time", do they?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you are trying to pass the return (a character pointer) to a function that asks a different argument (ideally a matrix would be a pointer of character pointer). So, I suggest you to change `char * init(int a){` to `char ** init(int a)` and its return to `return (char ** )tic;`.

Also, you should change the argument taken from the function display, `int display(int a,char tic[a][a])` to `int display(int a,char **tic)`

Answer (score 1):

Automatic objects ("local variables") go out of scope when the function returns. This means that the `tic[]` declared in init() no longer exists for the caller (here main()). Technically this means your program invokes **undefined behavior**.

You need to dynamically allocate the tic array with `malloc()`. There are good answers here on Stackoverflow how to do that, so don't ask again :-)